# VB6 Outlook Add-in works in Outlook 2013 but only if full Office is installed?

Tags: ms-office

I have a VB6 Outlook add-in. This is tested and working on a Windows 7 64bit machine, with 32bit OFFICE installed.

On another PC, Windows 7 64bit, 32bit OUTLOOK install, the add-in does not load. It is not listed in the list of COM add-ins, and when I try to add it to that list manually, it does not appear!

I assume that there is some dependancy with some office DLLs causing the issue but I don't know how to troubleshoot to find out where the issue lies.

Can anyone give me any tips??

Thanks in advance!

Comment: We need more information.  Specific error messages are great.

Comment: That's the problem though - there are no error messages!

Comment: Oops, didn't finish that comment. So I run my installer which would normally register all the necessary DLLs and register the main dll with Outlook. This is not working - the add-in does not display. I go to the list of Com+ add-ins, and click to add, select the dll... nothing happens - doesn't get added to the list at all, and no error message. On the other PC, with full office installed, this just works fine. If there are any tips on how to find where an error might be logged, that would be a start :-S

Comment: Verify you have choosen to install every compontent on the machine this isn't working on.  My guess you didn't install require compontent

Comment: Hi - the add-in has been installed in exactly the same manner on both PC's. I agree that there is a component missing somewhere - most likely a component of Office that is no longer installed by default in Outlook stand alone.

Comment: I have done extensive research on this - I don't post anything on here without first trying to find an answer myself. The thing I am stuck with is how to find out what component is missing or what error is being thrown when trying to add the component which Outlook is just not telling me. I am aware Office is supposed to have a log file (though I forget it's name) but even that is not present when only Outlook is installed. I am not necessarily asking how to SOLVE the problem, just how I go about pinpointing the problem in the first place!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I got exactly the same problem until I realized the problem was coming from C:\Program Files (x86)\Common Files\DESIGNER\MSADDNDR.DLL, that is brought by Office 2013 Pro with a file modified in 2010, and not with the family version. Check out http://blogs.msdn.com/b/vsod/archive/2012/11/21/vb6-based-add-ins-may-fail-to-work-on-office-2013.aspx and http://support.microsoft.com/kb/2792179 that mention this issue. Another important thing to note that that the Family edition looks to be a ClickToRun version (simili AppV virtualized application and Professional version is a fully installed version).

Comment: Brilliant! Thank you - not only did this solve this problem, but also another one which I have just asked another question about! My hero!!

Comment: Hi, I am having the same issue, But now these links are not working. Is there any way I can get the solution for this?