# VB6 Compile Outlook add-in - Compile Error: Automation Type Not supported in Visual basic

Tags: vb6, outlook, outlook-addin, office-2013, outlook-2013

I have got an infuriating problem trying to compile a VB6 Outlook Add-in component following an upgrade of Office on the same PC to Office 2013 Pro Plus.

The error

> Compile Error: Automation type not supported in Visual Basic

is being thrown on the line:

```
Implements IDExtensibility2
```

I will paste the full code from that file below.

On another PC, I managed to get everything set up, and upgrade Office to 2012 and it compiled no problem, but on that same PC now - I get the same error. I have messed around a lot with the Office install in the interim so I couldn't accurately tell you what I did in between it working and not working, but the bottom line is it seems it shouldn't be beyond possibility to do what I am trying to do (as I have done it!), I just need some guidance on what I may need to do to get back to a working setup. Any ideas??

```
Implements IDTExtensibility2
Private gBaseClass As New clsOlkAddIn

Private Sub IDTExtensibility2_OnAddInsUpdate(custom() As Variant)
'To Be Declared for IDTExtensibility2
End Sub
Private Sub IDTExtensibility2_OnBeginShutdown(custom() As Variant)
'To Be Declared for IDTExtensibility2
End Sub
Private Sub IDTExtensibility2_OnConnection(ByVal Application As Object, _
ByVal ConnectMode As AddInDesignerObjects.ext_ConnectMode, _
ByVal AddInInst As Object, custom() As Variant)

gBaseClass.InitHandler Application, AddInInst.ProgId

End Sub

Private Sub IDTExtensibility2_OnDisconnection(ByVal RemoveMode _
As AddInDesignerObjects.ext_DisconnectMode, custom() As Variant)
Dim objCB As Office.CommandBar
On Error Resume Next
'If RemoveMode = ext_dm_UserClosed Then
    Set objCB = golApp.ActiveExplorer.CommandBars("Addin")
    objCB.FindControl(Type:=msoControlPopup, Tag:="Menu").Delete
    objCB.FindControl(Type:=msoControlButton, Tag:="AddEmailsButton").Delete
    objCB.FindControl(Type:=msoControlButton, Tag:="SyncContactsButton").Delete
    objCB.FindControl(Type:=msoControlButton, Tag:="SyncTasksButton").Delete
    objCB.FindControl(Type:=msoControlButton, Tag:="SyncCalendarButton").Delete

    objCB.Delete
'End If
gBaseClass.UnInitHandler
    Set gBaseClass = Nothing
End Sub
Private Sub IDTExtensibility2_OnStartupComplete(custom() As Variant)
'To Be Declared for IDTExtensibility2
End Sub
```

Comment: Apologies - after struggling with this, I happened across the answer by re-reading an answer to a previous post.

Comment: Installing VB6 service pack 6 and the latest update roll up resolved the problem - as is suggested within the links in the answer to this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15118125/vb6-outlook-add-in-works-in-outlook-2013-but-only-if-full-office-is-installed .

Answer (score 1):

Another cause of this error, as I found today is having an optional parameter on a function and giving it a default, e.g.

Public Function Foo(MyString as String, Optional MyVariant as variant = null)

Changing this to:

Public Function Foo(MyString as String, Optional MyVariant as variant)

Solved it, I didn't get there as simply as it looks above though (hence, why I'm hanging around here), I did change the optional parameter to a string first, which worked, in fact, even with a variant parameter, having a default of anything other than Null worked. It was the default of Null that was causing the error.

Comment: This is true. Also, I have seen the error with default values of `Empty`, too.

Answer (score 0):

As you've confirmed in your answer (in comments), ensuring you've upgraded to the latest service pack is always the best option unless you know you're relying upon features that were dropped or changed in later service packs.

Answer (score 0):

Installing the "Cumulative update rollup for the Visual Basic 6.0 Service Pack 6 Runtime Extended Files" (https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/957924/description-of-the-cumulative-update-rollup-for-the-visual-basic-6-0-s) resolved this error in my instance.